# Fields of math to learn to understand this paper

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves, research

I was looking at the [Davidson $2021$ fellows](https://www.davidsongifted.org/gifted-programs/fellows-scholarship/fellows/current-and-past-fellows/2021-fellows/) and decided to take a look at Apoorva's paper. What fields of math do I need to learn to understand her [research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.11093.pdf)? Currently I know most of Complex Analysis but that is it. I am thinking the paper is using algebraic number theory because of the use of sets and elliptic curves.

Comment: Riemann zeta function, the PNT, its generalization to Hecke L-functions, thus algebraic number theory, algebraic geometry, Galois theory, a bit of class field theory in imaginary quadratic fields, and so on.

Comment: I just saw in your profile that you are 13 years old only. You are very advanced, but in this case, is it the best to attempt to understand a research paper instead of studying in (good) books for example analysis ? (I think that having a strong background in **analysis** is a priority ; deepening "abstract algebra", "algebraic geometry" etc...should come in a second time.

Comment: @reuns What is the "so on"? Maybe put your thoughts in an answer. I do know zeta function and PNT (guessing that is prime number theorem) since they aren't that advanced.

Comment: Do you have a  relationship  with a university professor near you? Or, these days, by email or zoom  or skype?  Note that Apoorva contributed to the paper, but it has reached as far as the arxiv because Thorner is at Urbana-Champlain, I guess tenure track, and very active. Take a look at all Thorner preprints at https://arxiv.org/search/math?searchtype=author&query=Thorner%2C+J   Alright, 2016  student of Ken Ono.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes I do. What are you thinking about?

Comment: Mostly that you need more precise guidance than we can supply; you also are going to need far more support than a  website can manage. Anyway, try Ono's book  https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Web_of_Modularity_Arithmetic_of_the/ybucAwAAQBAJ?hl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the abstract, here are some keywords

- elliptic curves
- complex multiplication
- quadratic field
- Fourier coefficients
- holomorphic, cuspidal, CM (complex multiplication) newforms

Elliptic curves you can learn about from Silverman's book(s) and other places. Quadratic fields would be talked about in algebraic number theory or Galois theoroy (field extension by a square root). Holomorphic and Fourier stuff is complex analysis and Fourier analysis although when they say "coefficients" that just means "write this function as a sum $\sum_{n \in \mathbf{Z}} a_n e^{2\pi i n}$" and you don't need too much Fourier analysis to understand that part.

Complex multiplication and "newforms" would be covered in a book on *modular forms* which is something you haven't mentioned. I'm not *super* familiar with modular forms but I believe Koblitz's book "Elliptic curves and modular forms" is a good introduction.

Comment: @Will Ken Ono has multiple books. When I took a class from his student, Larry Rolen, we used their book on Maass forms (2017) in addition to Koblitz's book. I wouldn't be able to say which book is better suited with this particular paper in mind.

Comment: Trevor, good point.